# Adding polygon name as field to all points inside polygon in QGIS

Tags: qgis, fields-attributes, overlapping-features, point-in-polygon, layer-name

I have a single polygon layer with multiple blocks features named `"block 1"` to `"block 40"`. Within these polygons there is a single layer with multiple points. I want these points to get the block name listed in the `"blocknumber"` field of the points.

If points 1-6 are all in block 1, their `"blocknumber"` field has to state `"block 1"`. This would be fine manually, but I have to get this done over thousands of points. How can I done this task?

Comment: Try Intersect or Spatial Join

Comment: Please, do not forget about ["What should I do when someone answers my question?"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 1):

There is a plugin, the Point Sampling Tool https://github.com/borysiasty/pointsamplingtool

Which does exactly what you want.

Answer (score 1):

Use this expression:

```
overlay_within('building', "id")[0]
```

- `building` is the name of the polygon layer
- `id` is the polygon's fieldname you want to attacht to the points within the polygon

*Orange points labeled with the expression from above to get the polygon's `id`:*
[image]